# How to create client socket using domain name

Tags: java, sockets

Hi I am using java for socket programming. To create client socket I have to pass IP and port. But I want to create client socket by passing domain name and port whether its possible.
My domain name refers to a static address internally. means i want to pass www.xyz.com instead of ip address.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket has a constructor, which takes a host name:

```
public Socket(String host, int port)
```

It will do gethostbyname() resolution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Java.net.Socket has a constructor of the form Socket(String,int), where the first parameter accepts a host name.

Answer (score 0):

first u have to get IP Address fo Domain Name...

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("www.xyz.com");
```

now var. ip contains the IP address so u can do what ever u want...